# Getting Unexpected client error and want to restart AppMaker from scratch/new

Tags: google-app-maker

AppMaker.google I have unexpected client side error. I want to restart from scratch. How can I reload a clean application of AppMaker?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open App Maker by following this link https://appmaker.google.com/ and it automatically redirects you to your most recent app(https://appmaker.google.com/edit/YourMostRecentAppKey) and it fails to load, then there are some tricks to create a brand-new app:

**Trick One: Create new app from Drive**

[image: from drive]

**Trick Two: Create app from docs**

Go to https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/ or https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/, select app of your choice and click `Open` button:

[image]

**Trick Three**

Open non-corrupted app directly from drive. If you have only one app and it is corrupted, then you can ask your colleague to create pristine app and share it with you.

**Trick Four**

File a bug(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410). Maybe somebody from support team will address it.

Comment: Fantastic.... thank you very much for your help. This allows me to open AppMaker. Thanks